# Eliminate all the text content for which there is both + and - character at the beginning of the line

Tags: bash, git, shell, filter

> -This folder contains common database scripts.
>
> +This folder contains common database scripts.
>
> +New Line

So here in the above case - I want to delete the first two lines ie. having both a + and - character at the beginning.

i.e
Resultant would be like

> +New Line

How can I achieve this in Shell/Bash/git.

Comment: Are the `-` lines always before the `+` lines? And are the `-` and `+` lines always next to each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an `awk` solution:

```
cat example

-This folder contains common database scripts.

+This folder contains common database scripts.

+New Line


awk 'f~/+ || -/ && /+ || -/ {f=$0;next} NR>1 {print f} {f=$0} END {print}' example

+New Line
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the lines in a file called `plusminus.txt` and you don't mind the lines coming out sorted, this will do the job. It will work whatever the order of the `+` and `-` lines, and matching `+` and `-` lines don't need to be next to each other.

```
comm -23 <(grep '^+' plusminus.txt | sort) \
         <(sed -n 's/^-/+/p' plusminus.txt | sort)
```